# How can I determine if an xml file is a valid msbuild build file?

Tags: .net, msbuild

How can I determine if a file is a valid msbuild file from a directory, which may have many xml files? I am reading all files in the directory, parsing them using BeautifulSoup, determining if they have a project element, and either of *itemgroup* , *target* or *compile* elements, but this approach is returning many false positives. Is it possible to make this stricter?

Comment: You probably can only use MSBuild API to load the XML files and see if any exception occurs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.execution.projectinstance.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_Build_Execution_ProjectInstance__ctor_System_String_

Comment: @LexLi The directory may have a lot of xml files with the element project in it. Is there another way I could determine this locally?

Comment: Why cannot you do some iteration?

Comment: @LexLi Because making a lot of API requests would be very time consuming. I need to do this for many directories.

Comment: Accuracy and efficiency cannot come together here.

Comment: @AdrishBanerjee in "API" lex meant you should use the MSBuild NuGet packages and the classes he linked to, not a web-based API service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters recognize that you should be using a standard naming convention for msbuild files. The industry uses, *.vcxproj, *.csproj, *.vbproj, (etc..), *.targets, *.props, *.proj (sometimes), and even less *.xml.

Second you should use the the msbuild project API to do all the heavy guess work for you. Don't reinvent the wheel: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project

Using that, you could use the Project class to load an msbuild file like so:

```
var p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project("C:\somefile.targets");
```

And then catch an exception if it's NOT an msbuild file.

Comment: `*.*proj` literally is what MSBuild is looking for and `*.vcxproj`, `*.csproj`, etc simply fall into that category.